# How to refresh the size of a div after adding elements to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element like this:

```
<div id="content" style="border: 2px solid black">
</div>
```

And through JQuery I add some new stuff:

```
$("#content").append($('<div></div>').addClass("box"));
```

where

```
.box { margin: 10px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black }
```

But the outer `div` does not resize when I do this, so I get an inner box that is sticking out of a solid outer box.  How can I get the outer box to resize itself when I add this inner box?

Comment: `$("content")` is a typo or did you forget to put the `#`?

Comment: Just forgot it in my example, not in the actual code.  Good eye, though :)

Comment: Are you doing any floating in your CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the selector if it's not a typo

```
$("#content") // id="content" (correct)
$("content")  // tagName = content
```

And change the display of the div to `inline-block`

```
#content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then the div will not occupy the whole row.

Comment: How cross browser is `inline-block`?

Comment: @Peter: Any browser and for IE8+. IE7 might support it, I use it on a website and it works. This list say it's incomplete for IE7-. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 1):

try this:

js

```
$('#content').append('<div class="box">&nbsp;</div>');
```

html

```
<div id="content" style="border:2px solid black;overflow:hidden;">
</div>
```

I hope his help!

Comment: Yeah the `overflow: hidden` did it, even without the JS change.  Can you explain why?

Comment: @luqui Likely because you were floating the `.box` elements. It's a CSS problem, not a Javascript one.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, huh, yep, I was.  I guess I still don't grok CSS.

Comment: yes its just a css issue here. i changed the js as well to show you a slightly better way of doing the same thing. i should've mentioned it :)

Comment: `$('content')` should be `$("#content")`

Answer (score 0):

`#content` is not resizing, since it's `width` is probably set in your CSS.

Either make it wider, or specifically size it appropriately.

Looks like `#content` must be over 40px wide, since the inner div has 10 margin and 10 padding, which is 20 on the left and 20 on the right.

So, something like:

```
$("#content").css("width","100%").append($('<div></div>').addClass("box"));
```

Or better yet, set up your CSS at the right width to begin with:

```
#content { width: ... ; }
```

---

If you are floating `.box` within `#content` then set the `overflow` of `#content` to `auto`(or hidden), otherwise the outer box doesn't "see" the floating inner boxes:

```
#content { overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added:

```css
#property { overflow: auto; }
```

and now size of elements is being recalculated when I show or hide elements.